# Layout overwriting

Tags: android, xml-layout

I have an arrow image in listview on right hand side. The text from other holders is overwriting on it. How can i keep a gap or space between arrow and justify all text. I was looking to configure it as no text should be aligned over arrow.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Author" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Description" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:text="publishedAt" />


    <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my answer it's perfectly work.

Comment: Just use padding_right with greater than 10dp on the base Relative_Layout, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Author" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgright"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Description" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgright"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:text="publishedAt" />


    <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgright"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

** This one is perfectly work **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dip">

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Title Of Song-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Author"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvName"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
        android:text="publishedAt"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <!-- Rightend Arrow -->

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/imgright"
       android:src="@drawable/arrow"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```